# Ionic: UPI Deeplink issue with iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, deep-linking, upi

I'm using Ionic for an app and trying to implement UPI with deeplink.

Everything working fine for `Android`. I'm using [`Web Intent`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-intent) and I'm getting the response.

Then, I got to know that I can't use `Web Intent` in iOS.

So I googled it and found few answers which uses [`In App Browser`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) to open the app.
My code looks something like below.

`this.iab.create(UPI_DEEPLINK, "_system");`

My UPI `Deeplink` is something like below.

`$upi = "upi://pay?pa=myupi@vpa&pn=My+Name&am=80&tr=OrderID123&tn=UPI+Message+Here&cu=INR&mc=UPI_MERCHANT_CODE&mode=05&orgid=000000&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-callback-url.com%2Fisupi%3Dtrue%26oid%3D1234"`

and then this URL is signed using `RSASHA256`

```
openssl_sign($upi, $binary_signature, $private_key, "SHA256");
$sign = base64_encode($binary_signature);
```

then added to `UPI Deeplink` as below

`$upi .= "&sign=" . $sign;`

> FYI I'm using `PHP` backend and adding url part only when the API is called from `iOS`
> devices, In `Android` using `Web Intent` works as expected. Once the
> payment is done, I'm redirected back to Merchant App (My App).

By using above deeplink, App opens `UPI` application and payment also made successfully. but the app wont open the Merchant app/the given `URL` (I've tried deeplinking my app instead of website URL something like myapp://callback-url, but UPI needs http/https URLs to be passed as `url` parameter. Documentation [HERE](https://web.archive.org/web/20200921110005/https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf))

I want the UPI app to open a URL/myapp with data of UPI payment Success/Failed response to iOS app.

How do I implement that?

And Yes,

1. I've tried adding `URL Schema`
2. I've added Associated Domain
3. Tried different UPI application

Comment: can you provide link or name of above mentioned application in ios app store ?